# How visual studio generates a class template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, t4, codedom

When we add a new class in visual studio, we get a template code

```
namespace MyProject
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

How visual studio generates this code? Does it use CodeDOM or T4Template or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has its own [project and file templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The C# class file template, for example, is included in a .zip file with a xml metadata file and the class template:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

Visual Studio most likely does a simple string replace of the various parameters defined between the $ dollars when it creates a new file based on these templates.

If you look inside the Visual Studio folder you can find various .zip files that contain the file and project templates. The file templates for Visual Studio 2010 are contained inside subfolders inside the parent folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates

Comment: T4 was first released back in 2005 according to Wikipedia so the Visual Studio templates must have existed before this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit